# g:availability not taken correctly

Tags: xml, rss, feed

I am trying to solve a issue with a XML feed for a platform. I am trying to get the availability and product type of products but I get this error in https://validator.w3.org/ : Undefined item element: g:availability

The code I wrote is this:

```
<item>
        <g:id>{{product.id}}</g:id>
        <title><![CDATA[{{ product.title | strip_html | strip_newlines | escape | replace: 'amp;', 'and' | replace: '&#38;', 'and' | replace: "Ã©", "e" | replace: "Ã ", "a" }}]]></title>
        <description>{{ productDescription | strip_html | strip_newlines | replace: '&', '&amp;' }}</description>
        <g:product_type>{{ product.type }}</g:product_type>
        <g:condition>New</g:condition>
        <link>{{shop.url}}{{product.url}}</link>
        <g:image_link>https:{{product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'large'}}</g:image_link>
        <g:availability>{% if current_variant.available %}in stock{% else %}out of stock{% endif %}</g:availability>
        <g:price>{{ product.price | divided_by: 100.00 }} RON</g:price>
        <g:brand>{{product.vendor | escape }}</g:brand>
</item>
```

And this is the attribute for availability:

```
<link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/{% if current_variant.available %}InStock{% else %}OutOfStock{% endif %}">
```

How to get this right by the XML feed? Thank you

Comment: Can you [edit] and show the complete XML that you generated and passed to the validator, rather than the template? (Make a [mre] if it's really long, e.g. edit it down to just one item, and check that you still get the same error.) Also, if you want help with the template, please add a tag for the template language, which you haven't mentioned at the moment. Finally, it's not clear what that link element has to do with anything.

Comment: I managed to take the availability now..This is what I did in the last 2 days. The next problem is that the link is not formating correctly in a tree. How to get the extension .xml and format as it should? [link for the feed from website page](https://www.jnstudio.ro/pages/google-base-product-feed)

Comment: You might want to take the [tour] to get an understanding of how this site works - it's not a traditional forum, where you can carry on a thread of comments to discuss different parts of a project. Instead, each page represents a single question, and (hopefully) the answer to that question. At the moment, this question has no answer; if you think it was solved in a way that would help future readers, you can add an answer yourself; if not, it should probably be deleted, as a permanently unanswered question doesn't really fit with the format.